# How to read dataframes containing strings which were originally arrays in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I have created a dataframe `df` with the following characteristics:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,5,3,7,8,4],
                    'B':['a','s','d','f','g','h'],
                    'C':[0, np.array([1.,4.,7.]), np.nan, 1, np.array([2.,3.]), 9],
                    'D':['9', np.array(['1', '8']), '6A', '1B', np.nan, np.array(['7', '3', '5'])]})
```

I then save the dataframe like so:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=True)
```

as I open the file i notice that the column D has apostrophes `'` sorraunding every number of the arrays. Here there is an example:

```
A,B,C,D
1,a,0,9
5,s,[1. 4. 7.],['1' '8']
3,d,,6A
7,f,1,1B
8,g,[2. 3.],
4,h,9,['7' '3' '5']
```

This wouldn't be a problem unless when I re-load the file back to python with the `pd.read_csv` function all variables are in the string format.

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=0)

    A   B            C             D   
0   1   a            0             9
1   5   s   [1. 4. 7.]     ['1' '8']
2   3   d          NaN            6A
3   7   f            1            1B
4   8   g      [2. 3.]           NaN
5   4   h            9 ['7' '3' '5']
```

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to reload the `test.csv` file in such a way that the output has the same types as the original dataframe that i had created?
You are allowed to modify even the way i save the file, just do not touch the way the `df` is defined.

Note: I tried to use the following line of code without success though:

```
pd.read_clipboard('test.csv', header=0, quotechar='"', sep=',', converters={'D':ast.literal_eval})
```

Comment: You could output to a different format to preserve dtypes. eg .[`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`read_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html)

Comment: What is the problem with the quotes? When you read back from your file you've got a numpy array ['7' '3' '5'], not a list with strings.

Comment: @ChrisA Thanks a lot I think that your suggestion worked fine!! :D